# problema con inicio de sesión en Laravel (comando make:auth)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy trabajando con el sccafolding que da el comando:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Para guardar a los usuarios solo he dejado en la migración `users` lo campos de

- `name`
- `password`
- `created_at`
- `updated_at`

Al momento de registrar, modifiqué el formulario para solo solicitar el `name` y el `password`.

Posterior fuí al `RegisterController.php` y modifique los 2 métodos involucrados, quedando así:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

Lo anterior funciona y puedo registrar usuarios; el problema viene al momento de entrar al `login` donde mi código quedó así tanto para el user

```
<div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="user" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('username') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="user" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('user') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="user" value="{{ old('user') }}" autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('user'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('user') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Como para el password

```
 <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Sin embargo al momento de tratar de iniciar sesión con los datos recién creados, no logro ingresar; no obtengo error alguno y solo se recarga la página

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es este caso debería funcionar haciendo el override del método username() en LoginController, dicho método viene del trait AuthenticatesUsers:

```
/**
 * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function username()
{
    return 'user';
}
```